# The HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting is no longer used & can be removed

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm using Haystack search (latest version) and Django 1.3.

The [getting started docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html#modify-your-settings-py) say to have a `HAYSTACK_SITECONF` setting, but when I try to `manage.py syncdb`, I get the error `The HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting is no longer used & can be removed.`. Removing the setting then tells me that `The HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` setting is needed, but that isn't in the [docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/settings.html) at all.

Are the docs outdated or did I mess up my install?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your link points to a 1.2.5 beta documentation while `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` appears to be a v2.0 alpha setting.

If you're using the development version of software you should generally expect documentation to be lacking. I personally use the stable releases that won't change on me unless I absolutely need one of the newer features (like django 1.4's new filterspecs).

http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-haystack/en/latest/tutorial.html